# Cannot draw transparent Component backgrounds

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, transparency, graphics2d

I have tried several tutorials and searches to figure out how to accomplish what I am trying to do. Basically I have a JLayeredPane with two Jpanels inside it. One for my game's drawing surface and one for my gui, like a pause menu. I have a png file with transparencies that I want to be the background of my gui panel that popups when the user hits escape. No matter what I do, the background of the panel (even tried making it just a component) is always grey with my png file drawn over it.

I have tried what others have recommended such as the following.

```
setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
```

and

```
setOpaque(false);
```

Neither of these has seemed to help and perhaps I am failing to do something else after these. I have traditionally done them after the constructor or within the constructor of a class that extends jpanel.

I am almost to the point where I am going to have one panel and draw everything myself but I would much rather use the built in java functions like boxlayouts, etc.

Edit Adding Working Example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Example {

private MyWindow gWindow;

public static void main(String argv[]) {
    Example g = new Example();

    g.gameLoop();
}

public Example() {
    gWindow = new MyWindow();

    // Initialize the keyboard listener
    gWindow.frame().addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) // escape key, show menu
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {           
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        }
    });
}

public void gameLoop() {
    long lastLoopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(true) {
        // Used to calculate movement of sprites
        long delta = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastLoopTime;
        lastLoopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Clear the canvas
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) gWindow.getBufferStrategy().getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0,0,gWindow.frame().getWidth(), gWindow.frame().getHeight());

        // Clean up graphics and flip buffer
        g.dispose();
        gWindow.getBufferStrategy().show();

        // Small delay before next cycle
        try { Thread.sleep(10); } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}

public class MyWindow {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JLayeredPane container;
    private MyPanel gui;
    private JPanel surface;

    private Canvas canvas;

    private GraphicsDevice vc;
    private Dimension dm;

    BufferedImage menuImg = null;
    BufferedImage menuImgHighlight = null;
    BufferedImage gSettings = null;
    Font font = null;

    public MyWindow() {
        frame = new JFrame("Jumper");

        vc = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();

        DisplayMode display = vc.getDisplayMode();
        dm = new Dimension(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight());

        container = new JLayeredPane();     
        gui = new MyPanel();
        gui.setLayout(new BoxLayout(gui, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        surface = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(0,0));

        frame.add(container, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        container.add(surface, new Integer(0), 0);
        container.add(gui, new Integer(1), 0);

        init_resources();

        canvas = new Canvas();
        surface.add(canvas);    

        gui.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.setOpaque(false);

        surface.setVisible(true);

        setFullScreen(display);

        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                setScreen(new Dimension(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight()));
                frame.repaint();
            }
        });

        canvas.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        canvas.createBufferStrategy(2);
        canvas.setFocusable(false);
    }

    public JFrame frame() {
        return frame;
    }

    public BufferStrategy getBufferStrategy () {
        return canvas.getBufferStrategy();
    }

    public void setScreen(Dimension dim) {
        int width = (int) dim.getWidth();
        int height = (int) dim.getHeight();
        this.dm = dim;

        container.setPreferredSize(dm);
        gui.setPreferredSize(dm);
        surface.setPreferredSize(dm);

        canvas.setBounds(0,0,width,height);
        if(gSettings == null) {
            gui.setBounds((int) ((dm.getWidth() - 200) / 2),
                    (int) ((dm.getHeight() - 200) / 2),
                    200,
                    200);
        }
        else {
            gui.setBounds((int) ((dm.getWidth() - gSettings.getWidth()) / 2),
                    (int) ((dm.getHeight() - gSettings.getHeight()) / 2),
                    gSettings.getWidth(),
                    gSettings.getHeight());
        }
        gui.setBackground(gSettings);
        surface.setBounds(0,0,width,height);
        container.setBounds(0,0,width,height);
        frame.validate();
    }

    public void setFullScreen(DisplayMode display) {
        setScreen( Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        vc.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
        if(dm != null && vc.isDisplayChangeSupported()) {
            try {
                vc.setDisplayMode(display);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {}
        }   
        frame.validate();
    }

    private void init_resources() {
        try {
            gSettings = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/gui/settingsWindow.png"));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print("Failed to load resources");
            System.out.println();
        }       
    }

}

public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    BufferedImage img = null;
    public MyPanel() {
        super();
        setOpaque(false);
    }

    public void setBackground(BufferedImage img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(img != null) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to post and example as setOpaque should work

Comment: Try setBackground(new Color(128,128,128,128));  Does this give you 50% image transparancy?  No?  Veryify the image really has an alpha component.

Comment: I've tried a number of different combinations and can't seem to replicate the problem you are having.  Maybe you need to post a runnable example which demonstrates your problem

Comment: Why did you create a GamePanel to paint an image at its actual size? Just use a JLabel, this is exactly what it does when it paints an image. Why are you using a Canvas? You should mix AWT and Swing components. I don't think a Canvas is transparent, maybe this is the cause of your gray background. Why are you playing with a BufferStrategy? Swing is double buffered by default. Don't use a WindowListener to close the window. Just use the setDefaultCloseOperation(...) of the frame. You still haven't posted an SSCCE like you where asked to do in your last question a couple of days ago.

Comment: If you don't understand why i use a canvas please re read the description. There are very viable reasons for doing so.

Comment: @camickr I think you mean "should *not* mix AWT and Swing" ;)

Comment: @lostdev, I did read the requirement. That is why I took the time to madk my comment, which of course should have said "you should NOT mix AWT and Swing" as MadProgrammer has pointed out. A JPanel/JComponent can do everything you want. You have had lots of time to post an SSCCE so I guess you really don't want any help.

Comment: @camickr I added a working example, not sure if that counts as an SSCCE or not as I've never been asked to provide one. I assume you just need a working example. You'll notice that there is a grey square in the middle of the black screen. Hit the escape key to kill it.

Comment: Well I really don't understand how any of your code works. As I mentioned earlier, you are using old AWT painting code and trying to add Swing components on top of it. I don't know why you can't just use a Swing application and do you painting on a JComponent. Then when you need a popup for you menu you can use a Glass Pane.

Comment: So instead of using a canvas and drawing my game entities like bullets and enemies, I should just make them components? Would that kill performance? I'm not sure That really addresses the problem but let me try the glass pane.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this, but, instead of calling `super.paintComponent` at the end of you paint method, try calling at the start....

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if(img != null) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

The reasoning for this, is one of the jobs of `paintComponent` is clear the graphics context and ready it to be painted on.  Event if the component is transparent, it must still clear/wipe the graphics context of anything that has previously been painted on it.  The graphics context is a shared resource, meaning that all the components within a given window may share the same graphics context, so it gets a little dirty if it's not "wiped" first ;)

You may also have issues with mixing heavy and light weight components, but seen as you adding the light weight components to the heavy weight component, it may not be an issue, but it's worth putting in the back of your mind... ;)

`JComponent` is transparent by default ;)

Comment: @lostdev I've played around with a number of different scenarios and I can't replicate your problem.  You need to provide use with a runnable example that demonstrates your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply some Physics over here...
The visible white color is combination of RGB max values...
If you are keeping RGB values to Minimum it will give you dark color (Black) and not the transparent one..

try to implement below methods..

```
(your component).setOpaque(false);
(your component).setContentAreaFilled(false);
(your component).setBorderPainted(false);
```

Hope so this will help you...

Comment: These methods do not exist on JComponent or JPanel.

Comment: `JComponent` is transparent by default AND the OP is already using it ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I added a Working Example.